# MySQL Export To Dump Project Folder (CMD command)

Tags: mysql

In MySQL Workbrench there is "Export to Dump Project Folder", I need to do same type of export with mysqldump in windows (CMD).

**NOT IN Self-Contained *.sql FILE**

Comment: you  say? ` $ mysqldump -P 3306 -h [ip_address] -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql `

Comment: no not in single sql file need to export as project, each table into separate file.