# How to dump mysql table into a csv file in mac os sierra?

Tags: mysql, database, macos-sierra

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts
INTO OUTFILE 'contacts.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I am running this query in sequel pro to dump a table in csv file. But it is giving me the error

### "The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement"

As far as i know, there is no my.cnf file in mac os sierra. it justs runs with the default value. Can you please suggest me how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Why as csv? because otherwise you have `mysqldump`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysqldump in CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040816/mysqldump-in-csv-format)

Answer (score 1):

**For MySQL installed via MAMP (on Mac):**

1. open "MAMP" use spotlight
2. click "Stop Servers"
3. edit ~/.my.cnf (using vi or your favorite editor) and the following lines:

   $ vi ~/.my.cnf

> ```
> [mysqld_safe]
> [mysqld]
> secure_file_priv="/Users/russian_spy/"
> ```

4. click "Start Servers" (in MAMP window)

**Now check if it works:**

a. start mysql (default MAMP user is root, password is also root)

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

b. in mysql look at the white-listed paths

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /Users/russian_spy/          |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

c. Finally, test by exporting the table `contacts` into a CSV file

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM contacts INTO OUTFILE '/Users/russian_spy/contacts.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
Query OK, 992931 rows affected (1.65 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Export To Dump Project Folder (CMD command)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367103/mysql-export-to-dump-project-folder-cmd-command)

By default, there’s no my.cnf file in OS X, and MySQL just uses the default values. To set up your own my.cnf, you could just create a file straight in /etc.

An example of the configuration file can be found here >> /usr/local/mysql/support-files/